# Example for a weak solution of Poisson's equation on a sphere that is not classical

Tags: partial-differential-equations, spheres, poissons-equation

Let $M:=S^2$ be two-dimensional the unit sphere. For a given source function $f \in H^{-1}(M) $ I want to find a weak solution $u \in H^1(M) $ that is not classical such that for all $v \in H^1(M)$ we have
$$\int_M \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \, dx= \int_M fv \, dx.$$

Is there any literature where I can find examples for such problems?

Comment: What do you mean by the Sobolev space $H^1_0$ considering your domain is a sphere?

Comment: Right, it should be $H^1$ I guess since there is no boundary if it is embedded in $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: To obtain an example, why dont you start with $u\in H^1, u\notin C^2$ and then calculate $f$?

Comment: I can't come up with a $u \in H^1, u \notin C^2$  on the two-dimensional unit sphere. I know that the Laplace-Beltrami-Operator on the two-sphere  should be
\begin{align}
\Delta_{S^2}&= \frac{1}{\sqrt {\det(g)}}\sum_{i=1}^2 \sum_{j=1}^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial X_i}\Bigl(g^{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial X_j}\sqrt{\det(g)}\Bigr ) \\
&=\frac{1}{\sin \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \bigl(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \sin \theta \bigr) + \frac{1}{\sin ^2 \theta} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 \phi}.
\end{align}. Do I need to use it?